# USB Keyboard not working in the bootloader, but does in BIOS and OS's

Tags: usb, keyboard, bootloader, bios

I have Windows 8 and Ubuntu installed alongside on my computer. However, my USB keyboard **doesn't** seem to work when supposed to navigate the GRUB menu. This was also a problem when i only had Windows 7. The keyboard works well in my BIOS and i made sure `USB Legacy Support` is enabled there, and i don't have any problems using my USB keyboards in the OS's.

To complicate the matter, my keyboard only works *sometimes*, but i have no idea how and when they do. Didn't have any luck lately. I have 2 keyboards, and the same problem occurs on them both.

How do i possibly fix this?

For Your Information: My MB is `Intel DH67cl`.

Comment: what is the manufacture of the keyboards? What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Manufacture : Logitech ( And I have one from Dell) Ubuntu Version:14.04 ( And i tried 12.04)

Comment: Grub as far as I know has no special input parameters for USB keyboard support. You could try a few things. First make sure you plug it into a USB2 or USB1 slot, not a USB3 (make sure your not using a USB hub for your keyboard. Connect it directly into the PC.)  Also, make sure your keyboard is plugged into the first USB port and try disconnecting other input devices. (other input devices can cause problems in legacy mode.)


As for the randomness, some USB keyboards will show up as a USB controller if you are pressing any buttons on keyboard while it is being detected.